# Stringbuffer unreachable statement

Tags: java, android

hello every one i have an issue. i want to show some data on android device but i am facing the error that StringBuffer (unreachable Statement) here is my code

```
public void ShowData()
    {
        btnShow.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor result = database.showAllData();
                        if (result.getCount() == 0);
                        {
                            showMessage("Error","Nothing is here");
                            return;
                        }
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while(result.moveToNext())
                        {
                            buffer.append("name"+result.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("userName"+result.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("password"+result.getString(0)+"\n\n");
                        }
                        showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void showMessage (String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: You've got a rogue `;` at the end of `if (result.getCount() == 0)`, meaning that the block after it isn't conditional... so it would always return. You need to get rid of the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` after `if (result.getCount() == 0);`. It terminates the if statement and statement following it is not conditional but will be executed everytime.